# Behaviour of char pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, declaration

I am reading a string from a file in the following format:
N // length of string
abcdef // string of length N

like that:

```
char necklace[400];
fin = fopen("file.in", "r");
fscanf(fin, "%d %s", &N, necklace);
char* left = &necklace[0];
char* right = &necklace[N-1];
```

However, when I declare `char*` before using them, **it gives me compilation errors**:

```
char necklace[400];
char* left, right;   // this causes the problem

fin = fopen("file.in", "r");
fscanf(fin, "%d %s", &N, necklace);

left = &necklace[0];
right = &necklace[N-1];
```

Could you please explain to me this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way to do it is :

```
char *left,*right;
```

When you do

```
char *left,right;
```

Then what you get is

```
char *left;
char right; /*This is not what you need you need *right but got right*/
```

So you see compilation errors

Answer (score 2):

`char *left, right;` should be:

```
char *left;
char *right;
```

Alternatively you can write `char *left, *right;` but as we can see from your example this is a bit more prone to error.